# How to import text data into Excel with leading spaces or misleading leading characters

Tags: excel, vba, text, import

I'm not exactly new to Excel and VBA code, as I have been using it for many years to do some rather extensive and complicated processes.

But, I have a text file from another system that I have downloaded to my PC.  I need to import it into Excel using a VBA script so it is repeatable.  The data is in fixed columns.

I'm using a Workbooks.OpenText method to open the text file, which puts the data into columns.  I used the Record Macro option to create the code for the method, then I cleaned it up.

```
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=sInputFile, Origin:=437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(26, 1), Array(29, 1), Array(42, 1), _
        Array(55, 1), Array(58, 1), Array(64, 1), Array(75, 1), Array(277, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Set wsInSheet = ActiveSheet
```

Some of the data has leading spaces that must be maintained.  Other data has a leading hyphen, which causes issues if it is brought into Excel in this way.  I've gotten around this in the past by adding a leading apostrophe to the data being imported.  This works well, but when the data is imported, it leaves the leading apostrophes in the fields as part of the data.  It doesn't pull the apostrophe out and just treat the following characters as text as it does if you type it in.  So, I have had to write code to basically do a:

```
    For Each cCell in wsInSheet
        cCell.value = cCell.value
    Next cCell
```

This will cause the cells to properly treat the leading apostrophes as denoting text data, leaving any leading spaces or other characters alone so they don't cause issues.

But, now I have a spreadsheet with over 30,000 rows and it takes a very long time to go through it with the VBA code.

I've tried importing the data without the apostrophe, designating the column as text, but it removes any leading spaces and left-aligns the data in the field.  I've also tried using the leading apostrophe and coding TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierSingleQuote, but that doesn't change anything.  I'm guessing the field would also need a trailing apostrophe.

I've also tried copying and pasting the entire column (normal paste, paste text only, paste formula, etc.), but it still leaves the leading apostrophe in the field.  The only thing that seems to work is to "update" each cell which then makes it act as if you just keyed the data into the cell with the leading apostrophe.

So, my question is: Is there a way to import the data with it retaining any leading spaces and just treating it as text, without having to go through this cell by cell process?  Or, once it is imported, to get Excel to recognize the fields as having a leading apostrophe to know it is text without having to loop through every cell?

Thank you,
Alan

Comment: `wsInSheet.UsedRange.Value = wsInSheet.UsedRange.Value`, instead of looping over cells. But this may be oversimplifying.

Comment: Hello, BigBen.  That works perfectly.  I guess I never thought of doing the entire worksheet at one time.  I appreciate your response.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).